# Managed Client Object Model NavigationNode Url Property Incomplete

Tags: client-object-model, navigation

It seems the Client Object Model is stripping out the "query" part of a URL stored inside the NavigationNode elements. I am wondering if this is a bug or perhaps I am doing something wrong?

Consider the following example. Site navigation is configured with a single item under the global navigation called `Affordability` and a URL that contains `?FilterField1=ContentType&FilterValue1=Affordability` at the end of URL for the All Items view:

```
var root = "https://server/sites/site/";
var ctx = new ClientContext(root);
var web = ctx.Web;
var nav = web.Navigation;
ctx.Load(nav);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
var bar = nav.TopNavigationBar;
ctx.Load(bar);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

// use the TopNavigationBar collection
Console.Write(bar[0].Title + "=" + bar[0].Url);
// outputs "Affordability=/sites/sites/Lists/List/AllItems.aspx"
```

It seems to strip off the actual filtering part of the URL. It is still present in the Navigation settings, and clicking the link in the Web UI works just fine. I understand I could create views for all the different filtering criteria - that isn't really what I am looking for though. I am curious to see if this is a bug in the Client Object Model (maybe I somehow have an old version?) or perhaps I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Oleg's post: http://www.thedotnotcorner.com/2012/12/12/add-a-query-string-parameter-to-spnavigationnode/

It seems that in a site with the Publishing feature enabled, the query string is stored in a separate property: UrlQueryString.

So to access the full Url+QueryString you would need:
    `bar[0].Url+bar[0].Properties["UrlQueryString"]`